# Jade input checkbox - problems with translation

Tags: pug

I have a problem with Jade templating. Here is my code where i want to display text only, but i am receiving __('Superadmin') in browser. What should i do? Please help!

```
div.checkbox
   label(for="superadmin")
       input#superadmin(type="checkbox" name="superadmin")
       | __('Superadmin')
```

Comment: This code is doing exactly what you tell it to - `| __('Superadmin')` will output "__('Superadmin')".  Is there something else wrong?